# Swift pods in Swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I need import Swift pod to my Swift project and I faced to a problem.
For example, I have the Swift [framework](https://github.com/maximbilan/CheckMarkView), and I created the next podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'CheckMarkView'
```

During pod installation I hadn't any errors, but my project doesn't see pod class.

[image]

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

You can check the issue [here](https://github.com/maximbilan/SwiftAssetsPickerController).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're importing your library?

Comment: Hard to tell from what we see. Did you open the xcworkspace and not the project? Did you import the headers (either bridging, or `import` before class declaration?

Comment: Have you imported the framework `import CheckMarkView`?

Comment: Yes, of course I opened the xcworkspace. And yes, I did import with `import CheckMarkView`.

Comment: When using `use_frameworks!`, you should probably be using `@import`

Comment: You can check this issue [here](https://github.com/maximbilan/SwiftAssetsPickerController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem, Swift pod framework classes must be public. Thanks for help.

Comment: There were in the pod framework: `class CheckMarkView: UIView {` and now `public class CheckMarkView: UIView {`

Comment: @MaximBilan Great! I have same problem and solved same as you.